# Validate a textbox input with an array list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am very new to AngularJS and currently I am working on a form which is designed in angularjs.

My task is to validate a textbox input with a list. If the value entered in textbox is not present in the list then it should throw a validation error.

I have written the below lines of code for getting the list items through rest API:

```
app.factory("EatonScanningFactory", ['$http', function($http) {

    var EatonScanningFactoryObj = {};
    EatonScanningFactoryObj.GetToolMaxTimeList = function (columnName) {
        return $http({

            method: 'GET',

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
            + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tool%20Max%20Time')/Items/"
            + "?$select=Text,Value&$orderby=Text&$filter=Title eq '" + columnName + "'",

            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

        });
    }
```

It will return the list items into an array.
The below lines of code are for accessing calling the above function:

```
    var getToolId = EatonScanningFactory.GetToolMaxTimeList('ToolNumber');
    var getMaxLife = EatonScanningFactory.GetToolMaxTimeList('MaxLife');
```

I am unable to proceed further as I am not sure how to validate if my text box input is available in the list or not.

Please help

Comment: Can you post a sample of your list ? what does it look like in JSON ?

Comment: List has two columns "ToolNumber" & "MaxLife".

Comment: It would be easy id you post a sample.

Comment: ToolNumber      Max Life
123456                45
223365                60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there here is a plausible solution **as an example**:

```
$scope.list = EatonScanningFactory.GetToolMaxTimeList('MaxLife');
```

**Javascript (Native) Example:**

```
function validateList() {
    var IsInList = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {

        if ($("#textbox").val() == $scope.list[i].listvalue) {
            IsInList = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    return IsInList;
}
```

**Angular Example:**

```
$scope.validateFunction = function() {  
    angular.forEach($scope.list, function(value, key){
        var IsInList = false;

        if($("#textbox").val() == value.listvalue) {
            IsInList = true;
            break;
        }
    });

    return IsInList;
}

//Invoke the function like follow:
$scope.validateFunction();
```

Comment: @TheAwesomeCoder :  its giving an error "length" is not a property?

Comment: Sorry for getting back only now, I had to do some stuff. The length property returns the total items in the object or array starting from 1 upwards. Try console.log(yourobject) / or from example console.log($scope.list) and see what the data looks like this will give you an indication to if your data is correctly formatted in object/array. If it is not properly formatted from the JSON response, simply use $scope.list = JSON.parse($scope.list); //this should convert it back to readable javascript oject.

Comment: can we do it through angular.foreach(var in variable).. If so please canyou please letm e know the syntax?